# Fullscreen Lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

but I want to open link and automatically open the Lightbox on fullscreen mode. How can I modifier this code to do this?

```html
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
<div id="fancyboxID-NAME" class="hentry" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">[powerbi id="4273" height="100%"]</div>
</div>
<p><a class="fancybox-inline" href="#fancyboxID-NAME">LAUNCH DASHBOARD</a></p>
```

Comment: [Fancybox 3 Fullscreen by default](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1280).

Comment: What version are you using?